# How to save model.tar.gz file in sagemaker using Estimator

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I am not able to save model artifacts in S3 bucket using below code. I am successfully able to save the result in output data path and training job is getting completed successfully. I am using the following piece of code.

Can anyone please confirm how do we save the model_artifacts in model-dir using below code.

```
# train.py code
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function
import os
import sys
import pandas as pd

prefix = '/opt/ml/'

input_dir = prefix + 'input/data'
output_data_dir = os.path.join(prefix, 'output/data')
model_dir = os.path.join(prefix, 'model')

channel_name='training'
training_path = os.path.join(input_dir, channel_name)

# The function to execute the training.
def train():
    print('Starting the training.')
    # Take the set of files and read them all into a single pandas dataframe
    input_files = [ os.path.join(training_path, file) for file in os.listdir(training_path) ]
    raw_data = [ pd.read_csv(file, header=None) for file in input_files ]
    input_data = pd.concat(raw_data)
    
    print(pd.DataFrame(input_data))
    
    output_data = input_data.to_csv(os.path.join(output_data_dir, 'output.csv'), header=False, index=False)
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    train()

# Below are the S3 input and output paths :
output_path = "s3://{}/{}".format(bucket, prefix_output)
S3_input = "s3://{}/{}".format(bucket, prefix)

#Estimator Code

test_estimator = sagemaker.estimator.Estimator(ecr_image,                                # ECR image arn,
                                          role=role,                                 # execution role
                                          instance_count=1,                     # no. of sagemaker instances
                                          instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge',         # instance type
                                          output_path=output_path,              # output path to store model outputs
                                          base_job_name='sagemaker-job1',       # job name prefix
                                          sagemaker_session=session             # session
                                         )

# Launch instance and start training
test_estimator.fit({'training':S3_input})
```

What is missing in this code?

Answer (score 4):

Sagemaker save automatically to `output_path` everything that is inside your model directory, so everything that is in `/opt/ml/model`. If the training job complete successfully, at the end Sagemaker takes everything in that folder, create a `model.tar.gz` and upload to your `output_path` in a folder with the same name of your training job (sagemaker create this folder).
You can also use the environmental variable `SM_OUTPUT_DATA_DIR`, which by default points to `/opt/ml/output/data` and put non-model training artifacts (e.g. evaluation results), Sagemaker will create an archive from that folder named `output.tar.gz` and will upload it in the same folder of the `model.tar.gz`  on S3.

I don't understand exactly what you mean with "result", but whatever you want to put in that archive, it's up to you to save it in your `model_dir`.
So for example this how I save my model in both json and H5, the first will be in the `output.tar.gz` archive, the latter in the `model.tar.gz`

```
output_artifacts = os.environ.get('SM_OUTPUT_DATA_DIR')

with open(os.path.join(output_artifacts,"model.json"), "w") as json_file:
        json_file.write(model_json) 

model_directory = os.environ.get('SM_MODEL_DIR')
model.save(os.path.join(model_directory, 'model.h5'))
```

Comment: Thank You for your quick response. In above example, I am reading the file from input data location and storing the same file again in output location.(result). But In actual program, I will perform some AI operations on that DataFrame and will save that output file in output location.

Comment: Now I want to create the endpoint using the above program but I am not able to do that as it is not creating the model.tar.gz file. I want to know what exactly this model.tar.gz file contains and how will I create that model  and save that file in output location for above program?

Comment: model.tar.gz will contain every file that is inside /opt/ml/model .. so every file you put there, you will find in the archive. Anyway I know nothing about endpoints, so I don't know if sagemaker has some sort of automatism to upload file at the end of the invocation, you have to read the documentation. An alternative is to use boto3 and manually upload that file..

Comment: I want to automate the above code using lambda and for that I need to create the endpoint. Can anyone please confirm how to create the endpoint for the above code or any other suggestions/steps that needs to be performed??