# AWS Sagemaker - Custom Training Job not saving Model output

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, machine-learning, deployment, amazon-sagemaker

I'm running a training job using AWS SageMaker and i'm using a custom Estimator based on an available docker image from AWS. I wanted to get some feedback on whether my process is correct or not prior to deployment.

I'm running the training job in a docker container using 'local' in a SageMaker notebook instance and the training job runs successfully. However, after the job completes and saves the model to opt/model/models within the docker image, once the docker container exits, the model saved from training is lost. Ideally, i'd like to use the model for inference, however, I'm not sure about the best way of doing it. I have also tried the training job after pushing the image to ECR, but the same thing happens.

It is my understanding that the docker state is lost, once the image exits, as such, is it possible to persist the model that was produced in training in the image? One option I have thought about is saving the model output to an S3 bucket once the training job is complete, then pulling that model into another docker image for inference. Is this expected behaviour and the correct way of doing it?

I am fairly new to using SageMaker but i'd like to do it according to best practices. I've looked at a lot of the AWS documents and followed the tutorials but it doesn't seem to mention explicitly if this is how it should be done.

Thanks for any feedback on this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save model.tar.gz file in sagemaker using Estimator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66205498/how-to-save-model-tar-gz-file-in-sagemaker-using-estimator)

Comment: what happens when you save the model to `/opt/ml/model/` ?

Comment: Thank for the link. I had a look at that post previously, but after some investigation and the points raised in the answer below, I found that the models were indeed being saved to S3, even when doing training in 'local' mode. I initially thought that it only saved, to S3 when it was training in on an online instance. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to Rok's comment on saving a model file when you're using a custom estimator. That said, SageMaker built-in estimators save the model artifacts to S3. To make inferences using that model, you can either use a [real-time inference endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/realtime-endpoints.html) for real time predictions, or a [batch transformer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/batch-transform.html) to run inferences in batch mode. In both cases, you'll have to point the configuration to the container for inference and the model artifacts. the [amazon-sagemaker-examples](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples#advanced-amazon-sagemaker-functionality) repository has examples for common frameworks, especially, the [scikit-learn example](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/advanced_functionality/scikit_bring_your_own/scikit_bring_your_own.ipynb) has detailed explanations.

Also, make sure the model is being saved to `/opt/ml/model/`, not `opt/model/models` as mentioned in your question.

Comment: Thank you! I had a look at that post previously, but after some investigation and your points raised, I found that the models were indeed being saved to S3, even when doing training in 'local' mode. I initially thought that it only saved, to S3 when it was training in on an online instance. Thanks again.